# need a javascript or jquery library to convert xpath to selectable CSS3 format in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, css

how can i convert xpath like

```
/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[1]/a[5]

html > body > div[3] > ul > li[1] > a[5]
```

i believe, index is not supported with CSS3 selectors....so how to deal with this ?

Comment: Yes, it is supported http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find that Sizzle/jQuery can't apply your CSS3 selector it might be better to use the [XPath plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/xpath) which was part of the original release of jQuery (and then removed since few people actually used it).

XPath implementations in browsers tends to be much [faster](http://ejohn.org/blog/xpath-overnight/) than the CSS engines. Also having JS parse & convert an XPath expression into CSS3 then having jQuery munge that into something the browser can implement (generally CSS2.1 selectors with a bit of JS assistance) is going to be **much** slower than executing the XPath directly in the browser.

Not only that, but there are things that XPath can do that CSS can't. For example:
`//h3[class="blog-title"]/../../div[class="blog-entry"]//input[fn:floor(value) &gt; 3]`
which isn't overly complex for XPath to execute, but impossible for CSS alone - moving back up the DOM and executing a function as part of the expression can't (to my knowledge) be done yet, even in CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

the xpath implementation in IE is very, very slow. even terrifying slow in IE6 thats why most tend to use CSS selectors based on regex etc. like sizzle or the newest is qwery. 
for a index select you use in CSS the selector `:nth-child(n)`

```
a[5] = :nth-child(5)
```

i cant remember if it starts with 0 or 1 so it could also be 4.

also if you have different types of children within the parent you are selecting in, you can  use `:nth-of-type()` which selects only the given type. in your case:

```
a:nth-of-type(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 1′s CSS locator engine moved from CSSQuery to Sizzle, jQuery’s CSS selector library.
So you can convert

```
div[3]/ul/li[1]/a[5]
```

to

```
css=div:nth(3)>ul>li:nth(1)>a:nth(5)
```

and

```
//h3[class="blog-title"]/../../div[class="blog-entry"]//input[@value=3]
```

can be converted to

```
css=h3.blog-title:parent(div.blog-entry) input[value=3]
```

however `//input[@value>3]` cannot be possible or be tricky 
For more info visit: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Home

Answer (score 0):

Searched for quite a bit and finally found these 2 libraries. Hope it helps someone as lost as me:

1. James Padolsey's [CSS2XPATH](http://james.padolsey.com/scripts/javascript/css2xpath.js) that was used by YQL HTML at one point of
   time
2. [css2xpath](https://code.google.com/p/css2xpath/) - A generic CSS to XPath transformer

As this is quite a niche area, I welcome the community to make edits to this.