# How to convert a CSS selector to XPath in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, css-selectors

I'm looking for the equivalent of `Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for()`.

I found css2xpath however the result from Nokogiri actually works, while css2xpath returns a selector that doesn't.

The result I'm looking for would be something like this:

`["//div[@id = 'my_div']//*[position() = 1 and self::table]//*[position() = 1 and self::tbody]//*[position() = 2 and self::tr]//*[position() = 1 and self::td]//*[position() = 1 and self::table]//*[position() = 1 and self::tbody]//*[position() = 2 and self::tr]//*[position() = 2 and self::td]"]`

Comment: Check my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652759/need-a-javascript-or-jquery-library-to-convert-xpath-to-selectable-css3-format-i/28232174#28232174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend using a library to convert CSS to XPath.

Try [**css-to-xpath**](https://github.com/featurist/css-to-xpath), for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [convert-cssxpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-cssxpath).
This npm package also supports interactive console and simplifies XPath expression when they can be.